# no speed up in OpenMP

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, openmp

I implemented a parallel version of my simulation (using model simulation using heavily memory based Wolff algorithm) but its is 3 time slower that the serial version.

O do not know what to do. 
Here is some explanation what code does:
For each thread I have a 3d array of `int`s (of size 60*60*60 , 100*100*100) and these arrays are saved in `heap`(allocated by `malloc()`).
Nearly everything each thread does is dependent on these arrays (a lot of read write of these arrays).

Because arrays are in heap it is slower than the serial version?

Or because my program is heavily memory based (lots of read write) it is slower?

Or I miss something ?

Thank you!

```
void start()
{   
    /*initialize gnuplot*/
    init_gnuplot(config0);    

#pragma omp parallel
    {

#pragma omp single
        {
            calculate_threads_T_interval();
        }

#pragma omp barrier

        config c = config0;

        c.T_initial = thread_T_start[omp_get_thread_num()];
        c.T_final   = thread_T_end[omp_get_thread_num()];
        /*create new system*/
        System *system = newSystem(c);    

        /*measure initial values of M and E*/
        measure_Magnetization(system);
        measure_Energy(system);

        /*change system T to its initial value*/
        system->T = c.T_initial;    

#pragma omp barrier
        /*run the algorithm*/
        run_T_interval(system, c);    
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer definitely without seeing your code, but one potential reason for the slowdown is that OpenMP has some amount of overhead when creating/managing threads. If the task speedup is less than the overhead, you will see a longer execution time.

Heap vs. stack access time is normally negligible and architecture-dependent, but you shouldn't see a significant difference from that. If you're comparing with the sequential version where they are also stored in the heap, then that has no bearing.

I would check to see that you are using OpenMP correctly. Try implementing it on a few sections of code at first and seeing the effect.

Comment: i posted some parts of my code, is there any problem?

Answer (score 0):

Using a synchronization operation like barrier in parallel program is expensive as all the threads have to wait for the slowest thread to complete. In your code structure, there are two synchronization points.

First, you spawn a certain number of threads but then only one thread is calculating the thread interval while the other threads are idle and waiting for this single thread to complete execution.

If you can call calculate_threads_T_interval() first and then spawn threads you can eliminate one synchronization point in your code and this will help in small speed gain.

It is really hard to say what the problem is without looking at the full code but to me, this is one small optimization purely based on the pseudocode you have given.

This is a good read on omp barrier construct, its impact on performance and other possible issues that could arise from it http://jakascorner.com/blog/2016/07/omp-barrier.html

Comment: thank you for your answer!  but all the work is done in function  run_T_interval(system, c);  , i have to use barrier and single directives because omp_get_num_threads() return 1 outside of  parallel region.

Comment: is it normal that some time(for example when memory bus speed is reached) the parallel program runs 3 times slower than the sequential version?

Comment: my parallel code finishes in 45 s and the sequential one finishes in 15 s